# I'm having trouble referencing a nested subdocument in MongoDB with Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, api, mean-stack

I'm following a book that takes you through developing web applications with the MEAN stack. When I go to localhost:3000/api/locations/:locationid/reviews/:reviewid I get "reviewid not found" regardless if I type the corresponding reviewid or if I type in a random number, and I logged review to the console and it is null. localhost:3000/api/locations/:locationid works and I'm not sure what's going on. Any help is much appreciated.

So here is what my document looks like in MongoDB:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a9025348de0d78d8792e105"),
        "name" : "Hardee's",
        "address" : "200 W Main St, Pilot Mountain, NC 27041",
        "rating" : 3,
        "facilities" : [
                "Hot drinks",
                "Food",
                "Premium wifi"
        ],
        "coords" : [
                -80.469262,
                36.385647
        ],
        "openingTimes" : [
                {
                        "days" : "Monday - Saturday",
                        "opening" : "5:00am",
                        "closing" : "11:00pm",
                        "closed" : false
                },
                {
                        "days" : "Sunday",
                        "opening" : "6:00am",
                        "closing" : "11:00pm",
                        "closed" : false
                }
        ],
        "reviews" : [
                {
                        "author" : "Bigpoppa Eizenga",
                        "id" : ObjectId("5a902dfd2bb702dcaf1b85e0"),
                        "rating" : 5,
                        "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-01-23T05:00:00Z"),
                        "reviewText" : "Used drive-thru. Service was friendly an                                                                                                                                  d fast, even with 4 special order items. I would definitely return when in that                                                                                                                                   area!"
                }
        ]
}
```

Here's what Node.js shows regardless of the :reviewid I type:

```
> loc8r@0.0.0 start C:\Users\Galen\Desktop\MEAN Stack\loc8r
> node ./bin/www

Mongoose connected to mongodb://localhost/Loc8r
Getting single review
{ reviews:
   [ { rating: 5,
       createdOn: 2018-02-28T10:56:58.203Z,
       author: 'Bigpoppa Eizenga',
       id: 5a902dfd2bb702dcaf1b85e0,
       timestamp: 2018-01-23T05:00:00.000Z,
       reviewText: 'Used drive-thru. Service was friendly and fast, even with 4 special order items. I would definitely return when in that area!' } ],
  _id: 5a9025348de0d78d8792e105,
  name: 'Hardee\'s' }
null
```

Here's my controller, reviews.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Loc = mongoose.model('Location');

var sendJsonResponse = function(res, status, content) {
  res.status(status);
  res.json(content);
};

module.exports.reviewsCreate = function (req, res) {
  sendJsonResponse (res, 200, {"status" : "success"});
};

module.exports.reviewsReadOne = function(req, res) {
  console.log("Getting single review");
  if (req.params && req.params.locationid && req.params.reviewid) {
    Loc
      .findById(req.params.locationid)
      .select('name reviews')
      .exec(
        function(err, location) {
          console.log(location);
          var response, review;
          if (!location) {
            sendJsonResponse(res, 404, {
              "message": "locationid not found"
            });
            return;
          } else if (err) {
            sendJsonResponse(res, 400, err);
            return;
          }
          if (location.reviews && location.reviews.length > 0) {
            review = location.reviews.id(req.params.reviewid);
            if (!review) {
              console.log(review);
              sendJsonResponse(res, 404, {
                "message": "reviewid not found"
              });
            } else {
              response = {
                location: {
                  name: location.name,
                  id: req.params.locationid
                },
                review: review
              };
              sendJsonResponse(res, 200, response);
            }
          } else {
            sendJsonResponse(res, 404, {
              "message": "No reviews found"
            });
          }
        }
    );
  } else {
    sendJsonResponse(res, 404, {
      "message": "Not found, locationid and reviewid are both required"
    });
  }
};

module.exports.reviewsUpdateOne = function (req, res) {
  sendJsonResponse (res, 200, {"status" : "success"});
};

module.exports.reviewsDeleteOne = function (req, res) {
  sendJsonResponse (res, 200, {"status" : "success"});
};
```

And here's my route, index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var ctrlLocations = require('../controllers/locations');
var ctrlReviews = require('../controllers/reviews');

//locations
router.get('/locations', ctrlLocations.locationsListByDistance);
router.post('/locations', ctrlLocations.locationsCreate);
router.get('/locations/:locationid', ctrlLocations.locationsReadOne);
router.put('/locations/:locationid', ctrlLocations.locationsUpdateOne);
router.delete('/locations/:locationid', ctrlLocations.locationsDeleteOne);

//reviews
router.post('/locations/:locationid/reviews', ctrlReviews.reviewsCreate);
router.get('/locations/:locationid/reviews/:reviewid', ctrlReviews.reviewsReadOne);
router.put('/locations/:locationid/reviews/:reviewid', ctrlReviews.reviewsUpdateOne);
router.delete('/locations/:locationid/reviews/:reviewid', ctrlReviews.reviewsDeleteOne);

module.exports = router;
```

I think this is all the relevant info. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`location.reviews` is a nested array, so it won't get Mongoose's virtualized `id` getter. Deal with it as with any other JS array. Change:

```
review = location.reviews.id(req.params.reviewid);
```

To:

```
review = location.reviews.find(review => review.toJSON().id.toString() === req.params.reviewid)
```

**UPDATE:** working code.

Comment: Hi Miguel, thanks for the reply. I changed the line, but now I'm getting  a TypeError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at location.reviews.find.review (C:\Users\Galen\Desktop\MEAN Stack\loc8r\app_api\cos.js:33:65)
    at Array.find (native)
    at C:\Users\Galen\Desktop\MEAN Stack\loc8r\app_api\controllers\reviews.js:33:39

Comment: Sorry, I misstyped the property name. Should be fine now, check edited code above, please.

Comment: I'm still getting an error:    TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null
    at location.reviews.find.review (C:\Users\Galen\Desktop\MEAN Stack\loc8r\app_api\controllers\reviews.js:33:64)

Comment: Can you show the contents of the `location.reviews` array and/or the review?: just before the modified line: `console.log(location.reviews)`, and the modified line: `review = location.reviews.find(review => {console.log(review);return review.id.toString() === req.params.reviewid})`

Comment: There is only one review in the array currently, the one that's in the original post. Here's what outputs for console.log(location.reviews);

Comment: [ { rating: 5,
    createdOn: 2018-03-01T02:09:40.540Z,
    author: 'Bigpoppa Eizenga',
    id: 5a902dfd2bb702dcaf1b85e0,
    timestamp: 2018-01-23T05:00:00.000Z,
    reviewText: 'Used drive-thru. Service was friendly and fast, even with 4 special order items. I would definitely return when in that area!' } ]

Comment: Weird. Can you change this other line to see the content of the entry?: `review = location.reviews.find(review => {console.log(review,review.id);return review.id.toString() === req.params.reviewid})`

Comment: I'm not sure if semicolons needed to be added to what you just typed, here's what I put put in: review = location.reviews.find(review => {
              console.log(review,review.id);
              return review.id.toString() === req.params.reviewid;
            });

Comment: null is returned and I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null
    at location.reviews.find.review (C:\Users\Galen\Desktop\MEAN Stack\loc8r\app_api\controllers\reviews.js:35:32)

Comment: Ok, let's see if we get there: `review = location.reviews.find(review => review.id ? review.id.toString() === req.params.reviewid : false)`

Comment: `review = location.reviews.find(review => review ? review.id ? review.id.toString() === req.params.reviewid : false: false)`. This might also work as per Mongoose docs: `review = location.reviews.find(review => review.toJSON().id.toString() === req.params.reviewid)`

Comment: the log now shows the correct output for review! Thanks a lot!